# Match statement using moved matched variable throwing compiler error

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, match, borrow-checker, ownership

I am attempting to iterate through a `Vec<String>` of file paths and read the content of the files. However, the `match` statement throws a compiler error regarding the variable in the pattern. The following is the code:

```
    //paths: Vec<String>
    //get counts in paths
    for path in paths.iter() {
        let mut path_result: Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>;
        let file: std::fs::File;

        if path != "-" {
            path_result = std::fs::File::open(&path);
        }

        //match result with error
        match path_result {
            Ok(path_file) => { file = path_file },
            Err(e) => {
                match e.kind() {
                    std::io::ErrorKind::NotFound => { println!("{}: No such file or directory", &path) },
                    std::io::ErrorKind::PermissionDenied => { println!("{}: Permission denied", &path) },
                    _ => {
                        println!("{}: Unknown error", &path);
                        panic!("unknown error opening file");
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
        };
        
        /*get content from file variable*/
    }
```

This is the compiler error I receive:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value
  --> src/main.rs:60:16
   |
51 |         let mut path_result: Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>;
   |             --------------- move occurs because `path_result` has type `std::result::Result<File, std::io::Error>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
60 |             Ok(path_file) => { file = path_file },
   |                ^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
...
75 |     }
   |     -
   |     |
   |     value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
   |     value moved here, in previous iteration of loop

error: aborting due to previous error; 16 warnings emitted

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `test`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

The warnings are in regards to unused variables not included in this snippet.

I have attempted borrowing the path_file variable's contents, but receive the same error. My understanding of the situation is that, because neither `path_file` nor `path_result` are used later in the `for` block and `path_result` is rebinded at the start, there should be no issue even if the ownership goes out of scope past the `match` statement. However, that seems to not be the case.

Comment: The error message is weird, `path_result` is *inside* the loop so it can't be moved in the previous iteration. I would've expected a *"use of possibly-uninitialized variable"* error like [here without the loop](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e9830a710f94e65728dec7df0f8e71b2).

Comment: Looks like there's an [issue already filed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/70433) to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use uninitialized values in Rust. This code does not work:

```rust
// declare path_result here
let mut path_result: Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>;

// conditionally initialize it here
if path != "-" {
    path_result = std::fs::File::open(&path);
}

// potentially use uninitialized value: error!
match path_result {
```

The code above is also why you're getting the `value moved here, in previous iteration of the loop` error, because you're not actually initializing `path_result` in every iteration of the loop. Once you refactor the code to unconditionally initialize `path_result` in every iteration then it compiles:

```rust
fn example(paths: Vec<String>) {
    for path in paths.iter() {
        if path == "-" {
            println!("skipping un-openable path: -");
            continue;
        }

        let file = match std::fs::File::open(&path) {
            Ok(path_file) => path_file,
            Err(e) => {
                match e.kind() {
                    std::io::ErrorKind::NotFound => {
                        println!("{}: No such file or directory", &path)
                    }
                    std::io::ErrorKind::PermissionDenied => {
                        println!("{}: Permission denied", &path)
                    }
                    _ => {
                        println!("{}: Unknown error", &path);
                        panic!("unknown error opening file");
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
        };

        /* get content from file variable */
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0723f599dfc832e5e93ec70ee9789c4a)